# What happened to polymorphism for jOOQ-generated classes?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, jooq

Let's take the query from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237064/avoiding-casts-when-narrowing-jooq-selects):

```java
SelectConditionStep<Record1<String>> query = create
        .select(AUTHOR.LASTNAME.as("AuthorName"))
            .from(
                    (
                            BOOK.leftOuterJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR).on(BOOK.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKID))
                    ).leftOuterJoin(AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORID))
            )
            .where(BOOK.ID.eq(1))
        ;

//when
Result<Record1<String>> result = query.fetch();
```

If I try to replace `SelectConditionStep<Record1<String>>` with `SelectConditionStep<Record>`, I get

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: `SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record>`
>
> Found: `SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record1<java.lang.String>>`

and yet ...

```java
package org.jooq;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

/**
 * A model type for a records with degree <code>1</code>
 *
 * @see Row1
 * @author Lukas Eder
 */
@Generated("This class was generated using jOOQ-tools")
public interface Record1<T1> extends Record {...}
```

So ... what gives?

Unless I'm missing something very obvious, shouldn't I be allowed to treat instances of `Record1` as if they were `Record`s?

(And yes, I started questioning myself to the point I needed to check I'm not completely mental: https://ideone.com/0O4mOU )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just [how generics work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po?rq=1).

This does not compile either, with the same error message:

```
ArrayList<Animal> x = new ArrayList<Dog>(); 
ArrayList<List<String>> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

You may want to type your variable something like `SelectConditionStep<? extends Record> query`. This way, you tell the compiler that any subclass of `Record` is acceptable (which is not otherwise the case). If you do that, you will also get a `Result<? extends Record>` back at the end, though, no longer something typesafe in the number and shape of the columns.

Comment: It's amazing how very basic things I keep forgetting when I haven't used them in a while. -.- Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using wildcards for `<R extends Record>`

While the correct answer to your *specific* question has already been given by [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238163/521799), what I believe you wanted to do is simply not spell out the entire type signature of this intermediate type, because you don't need it and because it's tedious. You could use a wildcard:

```java
SelectConditionStep<?> query = ...;
Result<?> result = query.fetch();
```

Because throughout the jOOQ API, the `<R extends Record>` type is bounded by `Record`, this wildcard is still implicitly bounded by `Record` as well, so in principle, the above is implicitly the same as:

```java
SelectConditionStep<? extends Record> query = ...;
Result<? extends Record> result = query.fetch();
```

This means that when you iterate the result, you can still assign the elements to `Record`:

```java
for (Record record : result) { ... }
```

#### Caveat: Unions, correlated subqueries, etc.

The `<R extends Record>` type is used in a few API elements, including unions, correlated subqueries, etc. If you use a wild card, you cannot use your query as a subquery in those syntax elements

#### Side note regarding jOOQ's `XYZStep` types

As a side note, do note that it is recommeded you try to avoid referencing jOOQ's `XYZStep` types. Assign your query to `Select<?>` or `ResultQuery<?>` instead:

```java
Select<?> query = ...;
Result<?> result = query.fetch();
```